# Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof TextInput'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am creating a react-native component using Typescript for the first time. And I get this following error in line 51: `Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof TextInput`

Similar topics didn't help me. Does someone have an idea? Thanks

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export type InputProps = {
    label: any;
    inputStyle: any;
    containerStyle: any;
    touched: any;
    error: any;
};

const Input = ({
  label,
  inputStyle,
  containerStyle,
  touched,
  error,
  ...props
}: Partial <InputProps>) => {
  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Text>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput style={inputStyle} {...props} />
      <Text style={styles.errorInput}>{touched && error}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: {
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  input: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    minHeight: 40,
    padding: 10,
  },
  errorInput: { color: "red", fontSize: 12 },
});


const stylePropsType = PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  PropTypes.object,
]);

Input.propTypes = {
  inputStyle: stylePropsType,
  containerStyle: stylePropsType,
  ...TextInput.propTypes, // I have an error: "Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof TextInput'.ts(2339)"
};

Input.defaultProps = {
  inputStyle: styles.input,
  containerStyle: styles.containerStyle,
  touched: false,
  error: null,
};

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Try setting the component type explicitly:

```
const Input: React.FC<Partial <InputProps>> = ({
  label,
  inputStyle,
  containerStyle,
  touched,
  error,
  ...props
}) => {...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the problem persists :(

Comment: @rkhan perhaps you don't need the propTypes to be spread there? After all, the propTypes on TextInput will throw error when it receives wrong type of prop.

If you are worried about intellisense not showing these props, you simply could extend the TextInputs props (pseudocode) `export type Props extends TextInputProps {}`